# GWT - compile to html file

Tags: java, gwt

I'm new in using GWT.

When I heard about GWT I thought than I will be able to compile Java code to html+css+js files  and can use it offline without any webserver. Now, when I'm reading how tos about starting with GWT I see that compiled GWT application has to be deployed before starting it in webbrowser.

Is any way to compile GWT to plain html files and run it in browser by simply clicking some html file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `gwt.xml`:

```
<add-linker name='xsiframe' />
```

The reason is that files loaded from the filesystem are all treated as if they came from different *origins*, so it's really easy to be caught by the so-called *same-origin policy*.

By default (using the `std` linker), GWT outputs *.cache.html files that are loaded in an `iframe`, so, being from different origins, the code in the `iframe` cannot talk to the *HTML host page*.

Using the `xsiframe` linker (or the now-deprecated `xs`linker), GWT generates *.cache.js files that are loaded using `script`tags, which allows loading scripts *cross-origins*.

See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_Server#What_is_the_Same_Origin_Policy,_and_how_does_it_affect_GWT?

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas. This is what I need. It works. I don't event have to connect to server and use my gwt application as client. I want to only create simply html+css+js GUI application using awsome gwt features.